# How can CommonJS and ES6 modules be included in the same repo?

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

I have a NestJS/Typescript backend where I am trying to use two different third-party services that use different importing formats. The two are below:

[PDFTron](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/nodejs/get-started/integration) uses: const { PDFNet } = require('@pdftron/pdfnet-node');

[Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/add-to-existing-project-typescript-postgres) uses: import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

I have asked PDFTron support to see if an module import style similar to Prisma works for their service, but they have told me it doesn't. So, how can I use both third parties if PDFTron doesn't work in Typescript files?

For reference, my tsconfig file contains the below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "strict": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": ".tsbuildinfo"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Comment: You're using TypeScript, not ES6, right? What module format do you transpile your typescript files to? Please show us your tsconfig.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I've edited the question to contain the tsconfig. Is more information helpful?

Comment: Since you compile to `"module": "commonjs"` anyway, you can just use `import { PDFNet } from '@pdftron/pdfnet-node';` and it should work out of the box. Look at the .js output files - they will have the `require()` calls that the pdftron commonjs module needs.